# (Kashmiri Shaivism and Advaita Vedanta) one self in comparison to many permanent selves?

Tags: philosophy, advaita, kashmiri-shaivism

How do we enjoin one permanent self over many permanent selves like in the jonang/yogacara school of Buddhism?
one way I think is the fact that people can perceive the same things simultaneously, whereas in Yogacara doctrine which jonang is based on, every perception is based on the impression which gives rise to it and we cannot all have the same impressions arisen in us simultaneously. I don't know if this is a strong argument at all.

What are some reasons one self exists over many selves within either Advaita Vedanta or Kashmiri Shaivism?

Comment: your question is about Buddhism, not Hinduism. I think you have misinterpreted Yogachara (Vijnanavada) Buddhism.

Comment: I am talking about yogacara outside of chinese influences.